# For não espera terminar requisição, ele continua a contagem

Tags: ionic, angular, for, requisição

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em ionic e estou com um problema quando faço um laço de repetição. Nesse laço tem uma chamada de um método de um provider, que faz um requisição `put`. Meu problema é que o `for` não espera o retorno do servidor ele continuar a execução, como posso sincronizar o `for` com a requisição?

Meu código abaixo:

```
getAtualizados(){

let atualizados: Cadastrolist[]=[];

this.contribuinteProvider.getAtualizados()
.then((result)=>{
  atualizados = result;
  for (var i = 0; i < atualizados.length; i++){
    this.servidorProvider.update(atualizados[i].dados.cadastro)
    .then((result)=>{
      this.contribuinteProvider.remove(atualizados[i].key);
    });
  }

});}
```

Comment: Não dá pra usar o segundo `result`?

Comment: É porque o segundo result é a resposta do servidor. Ele retorna um código, por exemplo: Se deu certo ele retorna 200 se não 404, só que o for não espera essa resposta ele continua até acabar a arry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver, para isso eu usei Async/await.

```
async update(cadastro, id){
await this.servidorProvider.update(cadastro)
.then((result)=>{
  this.contribuinteProvider.remove(id);
});
}
async getAtualizados(){
let atualizados: Cadastrolist[]=[];

await this.contribuinteProvider.getAtualizados()
.then((result)=>{
  atualizados = result;
});

for (var i = 0; i < atualizados.length; i++){
 await this.update(atualizados[i].dados.cadastro, atualizados[i].key);
}
```

}